# Is there a better semantic way to markup an ordered list other than ItemList?

Tags: schema, semantic-markup

Is there a more effective semantic way to markup an ordered list other than ItemList?

Answer (score 0):

"better" is relative, like much in the world of semantics...
i always markup lists with `class="xoxo"`, to denote microformats XOXO open standard.
"XOXO is a simple, open outline format written in standard XHTML and suitable for embedding in (X)HTML, Atom, RSS, and arbitrary XML. XOXO is one of several microformat open standards."
http://microformats.org/wiki/xoxo